# Writing a proper answer in a velocity-time graph

Tags: velocity, graph-theory

In a velocity time or any other vs time graph is it necessary,while mentioning an instant of time as 1s,2s,3s that it is from the starting point?Do I always have to say t=2s from the starting point?Is it wrong to only say "this event happened at t=2s"?

Answer (score 0):

When we say the velocity of the object at t=2sec is x m/s we mean from that point where the time t=0.

Answer (score 0):

I think t=2s is not a wrong thing. Most of the questions have like, this and this happened at **t=2s**